# rescale and normalize x axis numbers in python3.2 and matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, matplotlib

I am working in python 3.2 and matplotlib.

The numbers of x-axis are between 0 and 1000000.

In my plot, the numbers of x-axis are long and overlap each other.

I want to re-scale and normalize them between 0 and 10 and also show the unit (such as 10^6) around the x-axis.

How can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use `set_powerlimits()`:

```
import pylab as pl
x = np.linspace(0, 1000000, 100)
y = x * 2

pl.plot(x, y)
ax = pl.gca()
xaxis = ax.xaxis
xaxis.major.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 4))
```